# How to transform wide data to long data by multi-columns

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

How can I transform data X to Y as in

```
X = data.frame(
  ID = c('A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C'),
  V1 = c(2.3,2.6,2.9,3.0,3.2,1.8,1.7,1.6),
  V2=c(5.5,4.7,5.0,4.4,4.2,8.0,9.0,8.5),
  V3=c(1,1,3,2,2,3,3,3),
  SEX = c("MALE","MALE","MALE","FEMALE","FEMALE","MALE","MALE","MALE")
)
```

```
Y = data.frame(
  ID = c('A','B','C'),
  SEX = c("MALE","FEMALE",'MALE'),
  V1_1 =c(2.3,3.0,1.8),
  V1_2 =c(2.6,3.2,1.7),
  V1_3 =c(2.9,NA,1.6),
  V2_1=c(5.5,4.4,8.0),
  V2_2=c(4.7,4.2,9.0),
  V2_3=c(5.0,NA,8.0),
  V3_1=c(1,2,3),
  V3_2=c(1,2,3),
  V3_3=c(3,NA,3)
)
```

Is there a quick method in R how to transform it to such dataframe? Thanks for any recommendations!

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can `gather` the columns which `starts_with` `"V"` into long format, `group_by` `ID`, `SEX` and `key` create a unique column (`key1`) to `spread the data into wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

X %>%
  gather(key, value, starts_with("V")) %>%
  group_by(ID, SEX, key) %>%
  mutate(key1 = paste(key, row_number(), sep = "_")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  spread(key1, value)


#  ID    SEX     V1_1  V1_2  V1_3  V2_1  V2_2  V2_3  V3_1  V3_2  V3_3
#  <fct> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A     MALE     2.3   2.6   2.9   5.5   4.7   5       1     1     3
#2 B     FEMALE   3     3.2  NA     4.4   4.2  NA       2     2    NA
#3 C     MALE     1.8   1.7   1.6   8     9     8.5     3     3     3
```

Comment: @Sotos but there is nothing to `unite` against. Do you mean to create a new column with `row_number()` and then `unite` ?

Comment: @Sotos `unite(key1, key, row_number(), sep - "_")` doesn't work for me gives me `Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context`. Does it work for you?

Comment: let me check... I was just guessing :)...Nope...not working for me either

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach,

```
library(data.table)

dcast(setDT(X)[, new := seq(.N), by = .(ID, SEX)], ID+SEX ~ new, value.var = c("V1", "V2", "V3"))

#   ID    SEX V1_1 V1_2 V1_3 V2_1 V2_2 V2_3 V3_1 V3_2 V3_3
#1:  A   MALE  2.3  2.6  2.9  5.5  4.7  5.0    1    1    3
#2:  B FEMALE  3.0  3.2   NA  4.4  4.2   NA    2    2   NA
#3:  C   MALE  1.8  1.7  1.6  8.0  9.0  8.5    3    3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much a one-liner with the new `tidyr 1.0.0` (release notes [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/09/tidyr-1-0-0/)):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

X %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(NUMBER = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = NUMBER, values_from = c(V1, V2, V3))
```

#### Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 11
# Groups:   ID [3]
  ID    SEX     V1_1  V1_2  V1_3  V2_1  V2_2  V2_3  V3_1  V3_2  V3_3
  <fct> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     MALE     2.3   2.6   2.9   5.5   4.7   5       1     1     3
2 B     FEMALE   3     3.2  NA     4.4   4.2  NA       2     2    NA
3 C     MALE     1.8   1.7   1.6   8     9     8.5     3     3     3
```

**Edit:** You can also use functions like `starts_with("V")` in `values_from =`.